# Taking arguments via command line for launch files

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to pass a value to a parameter in a node via the launch file.

I created a basic node that would print the parameter it read or it would give an error saying no parameter.

even though I pass a parameter the node is not able to read it.

I have added the code of the launch file and node below.

Launch File:

```
<launch>

<arg name="station" />

<node pkg="param_from_launch" type="trial" name="trial">
  <param name="param_1" value="$(arg station)"/>
</node>

</launch>
```

C++ Node:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Set up ROS.
    ros::init(argc, argv, "trial");
    ros::NodeHandle n("~");   // private namespace

    int param_1;

    n.param<int>("param_from_launch", param_1, 0);
    if(n.param("param_from_launch", param_1)){
        ROS_INFO("param_from_launch: %d", param_1);
    }
    else{
        ROS_ERROR("NO PARAM");
    }
    // Let ROS handle all callbacks.
    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}  // end main()
```

running the node separately gives me the expected output: `param_from_launch: 0`. but when running the launch file I get
`[ERROR] [1644580954.583154879]: NO PARAM`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/396021/taking-arguments-via-command-line-for-launch-files./) by [NOVA1323](https://answers.ros.org/users/89853/nova1323/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see two basic issues with the example posted in the question:

1. The `<param>` tag in the launch file set's the parameter name to `param_1`. So we will have a parameter `/trial/param_1` with a value determined by the `station` arg to the launch file. However, the node tries to read a parameter called `/trial/param_from_launch`.
2. You have not set the `output` attribute for the node. So even if your node did work as intended you wouldn't see the output messages you're hoping to see (except the calls to `ROS_ERROR`).

What if you change your launch file to:

```
<launch>

<arg name="station" />

<node pkg="roscpp_tutorials" type="trial" name="trial" output="screen">
  <param name="param_from_launch" value="$(arg station)" type="int" />
</node>

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2022-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NOVA1323](https://answers.ros.org/users/89853/nova1323/) on 2022-02-12**:
Thanks, I always thought that the first string was just a placeholder or message.